# How to convert [[ivar retain] autorelease] to ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, retain, autorelease

How to convert the following code to ARC?

```
- (NSString *) shardId {
  return [[__shardId retain] autorelease];
}
```

The following compiles for me, but not sure if there's any potential issue.

```
- (NSString *) shardId {
  return __shardId;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That code is correct – ARC will handle the correct memory management for you.

Comment: It's even better under ARC— because if the result immediately gets retained by the caller, the ARC method will actually detect this and forego the retain/autorelease *and* the retain at the call site too :o)